# Can new ever return nil?

Tags: ruby

I am working in a new code base that is written in ruby. I have never developed ruby before, so I have a very general question. The code has a pattern I find weird. When ever it creates a new instance of a class, it immediately checks to make sure it's not nil.

```
@client = Client.new()
raise("Client not initialized.") if (@client == nil)
```

In general can new return nil? Is this a common ruby pattern?

Comment: It's just a method, so sure, it *could*. 

Is it common? No, not at all.

Comment: This pattern is quite common in Swift for example where many Cocoa APIs use failable iniializers. In Ruby it is possible but rarely used - if the preconditions for creating an instance fail an exception is often raised instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Can it?** Yes.

It is possible to override the default implementation of `Class#new` (which calls `Class#allocate` and then `initialize`) with something that might return `nil`. However,

**Will it?** Probably not.

The default implementation of `new` will *not* return `nil`, and overriding `new` is very rare, and probably not great form (although it isn't neccisarily bad practice, there's usually a better way).